# unable to access files on a different physical drive from asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, iis, file-access, server.mappath

My website is published under c:\inetpub\wwwroot folder and I have some large text files on D: drive that I need to access. Let's say the exact location is D:\Test\test.txt. When my website runs it keeps failing on the `File.Exists()` check. I have tried the following but none worked:

- Created virtual dir from IIS to point to this folder and used `Server.MapPath` in code
- Gave Network Service read access to this Test folder
- Shared the folder with Network Service and in the website reference the UNC path

All of the above failed and the site still says the file doesn't exist, but it's there. Any ideas?

EDIT: Below are several attempts that I placed in Page_Load which failed:

```
if (File.Exists(@"D:\Test\test.txt"))
{ ... }

if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("TestVirtualDir/test.txt")))
{ ... }
```

Comment: Can you setup a symlink under wwwrooot to d:\? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042542/what-is-the-difference-between-ntfs-junction-points-and-symbolic-links

Comment: I can try that, however is it necessary? It seems like I should be able to access the D:\ files much more easily...

Comment: Based on what you already tried I reckoned you were out-of-options...I recall that iis doesn't like to wander off to other paths not under the application path. Maybe you should share the code/markup you use to serve those files on D:\

Comment: If you add a Trace.Write(Server.MapPath("TestVirtualDir/test.txt")) hit the page and see what is in trace.axd? The persmission you write are read, did you also give execute and list foldercontent? Are your sure Network Service is the identity that is used in the appdomain?

Comment: I verified that Server.MapPath points to the correct physical location. I'm pretty sure Network Service is used since I remember having to add this permission for a different website on the same server, how do I double check this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25034/discussion-between-rene-and-user1715925)

Comment: I checked and turned out you were right, it was using a different user acount under IIS user something instead of network service. go ahead and add a comment so I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure Network Service is the identity that is used in the appdomain.