# Is it possible to use special characters to represent a space in Windows?

Tags: windows, escaping, whitespace, filenames, long-filenames

We are using a proprietary application for inventory management and have discovered this application is unable to interpret spaces in file paths. For example:

```
C:\Google Drive\Invoices
```

Does not work, whereas

```
C:\Google\Invoices
```

does work.

Is there a special way to represent a space in Windows much like a URL string can use %20? For example `C:\Google%20\Drive\Invoices`.

Comment: what language are You using? is it C#?

Comment: Usually you would put quote marks around it, i.e., `"C:\Google Drive\Invoices"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 8.3 short name.

Try `dir /x c:\`

`Google Drive` should have a short name, probably like `GOOGLE~1`

Then you can use `C:\GOOGLE~1\Invoices`

Comment: This works, unless generation of short names has been disabled. [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx): "*Note  Not all file systems follow the tilde substitution convention, and systems can be configured to disable 8.3 alias generation even if they normally support it. Therefore, do not make the assumption that the 8.3 alias already exists on-disk.*"

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use short names if supported. Type `dir /x` and it's in the middle column.

[image: short name dir]

However it only works if short names aren't turned off. If short names aren't available the only way is making [a junction point or a symbolic link](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/278262-mklink-create-use-links-windows.html)<sup>1</sup>.

Run cmd as admin and type either of the following

```
mklink /J C:\ggdrive "C:\Google Drive"
mklink /D C:\ggdrive "C:\Google Drive"
```

This will create a link from `ggdrive` to the real `Google Drive` folder and now you can access `Google Drive` as `ggdrive`

However it's highly probable that you've used the path incorrectly. In some places you need to quote paths with spaces like this `"C:\Google Drive\Invoices"`. But if an application in the last 15-20 years doesn't support long file names then it is rubbish anyway. Use a better program or report to the developer to fix it.

---

<sup>1</sup> The differences between them is like this

- [What is the difference between NTFS Junction Points and Symbolic Links?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9042542/995714)
- [“directory junction” vs “directory symbolic link”?](https://superuser.com/q/343074/241386)