# Check if user has read permissions on a directory (powershell)

Tags: powershell

I have found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48997597/1306186) on how to check whether the current user has read permissions on a file with powershell.

How can I do a similar check for directories? (Without having to install additional modules.)

Comment: Something like `(Get-Acl -Path C:\temp).Access` shows the ACL's for a given object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bother with checking access control lists.

The proper way to check if you have read permissions on *any* object is plain and simple. Try to read it, and catch the "access denied" error.

```
try {
    Get-ChildItem "path\to\that\directory" -ErrorAction Stop
} catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException] {
    Write-Host "$($_.TargetObject): Access denied"
} catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {
    Write-Host "$($_.TargetObject): Path not found"
}
```

Comment: Trying this with a UNC-Path leads to an `unexpected network error` exception, but only on the first call. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: "UNC path" or "local path" are the same as far as `Get-ChildItem` is concerned, which means either it works, or you get "Access Denied"/"File not found". "Unexpected network error" sounds unrelated, I can't recommend more than googling the error message.

Comment: @Zulakis I've tested some more and I always get `Access is denied` immediately on UNC paths I am not allowed to read. Not sure what causes your "unexpected network error", but the UNC path is not it.