# What's the difference between Symbolic Link <=> Junction <=> Shortcut?

Tags: windows, hyperlink, symlink, ntfs, junction

In Windows using NTFS file system there are 3 different possiblities to create links **to folders**.
(For **files** there are 2 possibilities: hard links and shortcuts.)

A shortcut is a .lnk file which has several hundred bytes that contains the link Information.
But what about the other two possibilities: **Symbolic Links** <=> **Junctions**?
According to FreeCommander both link "files" need 30 Byte each.

I'm able to create a junction by using
`mklink /j LinkFolderToCreate ExistingFolder`
To create a symbolic link I use
`mklink /d LinkFolderToCreate ExistingFolder`

The `dir` command gives me the following Output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Temp\LinkTest\Folder>mklink /d SymLink ..\Link
symbolic link created for SymLink <<===>> ..\Link

C:\Temp\LinkTest\Folder>mklink /j Junction ..\Link
Junction created for Junction <<===>> ..\Link

C:\Temp\LinkTest\Folder>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 40A4-35D4

 Directory of C:\Temp\LinkTest\Folder

30.08.2018  12:09    <DIR>          .
30.08.2018  12:09    <DIR>          ..
30.08.2018  12:09    <JUNCTION>     Junction [C:\Temp\LinkTest\Link]
30.08.2018  12:09               918 Shortcut.lnk
30.08.2018  12:08    <SYMLINKD>     SymLink [..\Link]
               1 File(s)            918 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  63.696.363.520 bytes free

C:\Temp\LinkTest\Folder>
```

What are the differences between Symbolic Links and Junctions?
Which one would you take in which case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between NTFS Junction Points and Symbolic Links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042542/what-is-the-difference-between-ntfs-junction-points-and-symbolic-links)

Comment: I think this page answers my question best:
https://superuser.com/questions/343074/directory-junction-vs-directory-symbolic-link