# Are Windows directory junctions drive letter bound?

Tags: windows, storage

If one creates a cross-volume directory junction on Windows, from, say, C:\Foo to D:\Bar, and then reassigns the volume letter on the drive that used to be D: to E:, will the junction stay valid?

And the converse: if the drive that is D: is moved to a different SATA slot but keeps the drive letter, will the junction stay valid?

Comment: So they are drive letter bound. Make an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between NTFS Junction Points and Symbolic Links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042542/what-is-the-difference-between-ntfs-junction-points-and-symbolic-links)

Comment: Not really, no.